# C#: How can I raise an exception from an event handler in a class derived from TextBox?

Tags: c#, exception

I am developing a numeric text box, a control derived from TextBox that will only accept numeric input.  (Yes, I know there's lots of these, but the ones I saw are a lot more complicated than they need to be.)  My class overrides OnKeyDown() and checks to see if the newly entered text can be converted to a number, and if that number is within specified limits.  If the number is outside the limits, then an InvalidOperationException is raised.

When I tested this control on a form, I expected to see a unhandled exception message pop up, but it didn't.  I think this is because unhandled exceptions thrown from event handlers are ignored.  But since this exception is being thrown from inside the text box, there's no place on my form where I can catch this exception.

I suppose I can add an event to my control named BadValue, but then I'd have to remember to add a handler for that event wherever I used that control.  I want to be able to rely on standard exception processing, but I don't know how.

Thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: Why not just ignore the key press if it isn't a "legal" character? Or is there a specific reason you want to throw an exception and handle it in the catch?

Comment: The keypress is legal.  It just results in an illegal value.  Also, there are other ways the text box's text can change, such as pasting from the clipboard.  And I don't want to handle it in a catch in my numeric text box control.  I want it to be possible to handle it in the form containing my numeric text box.  But in order to do that, I need to have the code that performs the action that results in the exception.  There is no code that I know of in the form that I can wrap with an exception handler to catch this exception.

Comment: What about a NumericUpDown control?

Answer (score 0):

if u don't want the textbox to allow user to write numbers in it u can easily use a masked text box with a numeric mask 
if u r ok with the user writing numbers then showing an error message with invalid value u may use this try catch code

```
       try
        {
            int x = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The value is invalid");
        }
```

this will try to parse the value as int ..if it's not then it throw an exception 
u can use any other numeric data type of course depending on the value